# Can any one tell me that how can i publish my opencart extension in opencart marketplace?

Tags: marketplace

I have made extension in opencart 3, I want to publish this extension in opencart marketplace. I already have opencart marketplace account, So please help to publish my extension.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have a seller account on Opencart 
then there are two options then

**Manage your Extensions**

**Apply to become a seller**

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=common/home

then go on register and if you already have an account login here.

[image]

Now if you want to earn then go to **Apply to become a seller**
and follow further steps

Comment: It takes how many day to approve extension ?